# Python3 Sockets - PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted - running as root

Tags: python, linux, sockets

I'm having a hard time with this small socket program I have. The script runs fine one on Debian 11 server, but has the following error on an almost identical Debian 11 server.

```
root@box:/home/user/python# sudo python3 script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/python/script.py", line 18, in <module>
    UDPClientSocket.sendto(bytesToSend, serverAddress) # Send using created UDP socket
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

The file is owned by root and executable.

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 942 May 27 16:24 script.py
```

Here is the script, its pretty basic.

```
import socket
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES

serverAddress   = ("192.168.1.3", 3493)  #Packet Destination - IP/Port pair
sourceAddress   = ("192.168.3.2", 54921) #Source Socket - IP/Port pair
bufferSize      = 1024

data=b"garbage"          # message to send to server
key=b"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"                           # key to encrypt data
salt=b'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'                        # salt
obj=AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, salt)            # set crypt settings
bytesToSend=obj.encrypt(data)                   # encrypt the data

UDPClientSocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # Create a UDP socket at client side
UDPClientSocket.bind((sourceAddress)) # Set local socket for source ip/port
UDPClientSocket.sendto(bytesToSend, serverAddress) # Send using created UDP socket
```

I am running as root, script is owned by root, what is wrong here?

Is there something I am doing in the script that is not allowed by the OS?

Updates:

Uname for the box it does run on:
`Linux box 5.10.0-14-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.113-1 (2022-04-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Uname for the box it does not run on:
`Linux box 5.10.0-13-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.106-1 (2022-03-17) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Python versions are the same, 3.9.2.

Interface listing for the box I am attempting to run my script on:

```
# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: net1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 04:d9:f5:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp2s0
    inet 192.168.3.2/28 brd 192.168.3.15 scope global net1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: "Operation not permitted" is not a permissions problem.

Comment: If the two Debian servers are "almost identical", then what are the differences? that may be the cause of your issue.

Comment: Is `192.168.3.2` the correct address of the server where it fails?

Comment: Updated post with more info

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, mistake on my part.

Turns out it was the firewall. I have iptables with output filters, and forgot the iptables-save before the last reboot, so the output rule allowing the UDP sendto was denied.

Figured it out when I attempted ncat in udp mode and it failed with `WRITE ERROR`

I appreciate everyone's input though.

Answer (score 0):

Run this to update

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools pip
```

try again

Comment: No change to the error. Your command successfully installs pip-22.1.1 and setuptools-62.3.2 but does not solve the permission error.

Comment: Do you have use_pty set in /etc/sudoers?

Comment: No. But the script fails with or without sudo (while being run as root)

Comment: or possible run { sudo visudo /etc/sudoers.d -f python  }

Comment: sudo setcap cap_net_raw+ep $(which python<version>)